# Coloring specific type of the planar graph

Tags: algorithm, planar-graph

I've got a specific type of the planar graph and I found it interesting to search for an algorithm which will color its vertices [legally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring). About this type of graph, it's very easy and cool:

> Consider any tree **T** with **n>2** vertices and **k** leaves. Let's denote **G(T)** as a graph constructed from **T** by connecting its leaves into **k**-cycle in such way that **G(T)** is planar.

And the problem I came up with is to color **G(T)** with **3** colors. Clearly, **G(T)** as a planar graph, is **4**-colorable, but I think (don't have a proof) that it is almost always **3**-colorable due to its simplicity. Almost always means that only if **T** is a [star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) and only with odd number of leaves, then **G(T)** is **4**-colorable.

I am looking for some algorithm, or maybe proof of my assumptions which could be easily transformed into an algorithm. I would be very very grateful for any help, hints.

In case I wasn't clear enough I'll give an example:

Let T be a tree with edges E(T) = { {1,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {4,5} } and then E(G(T)) = sum of the sets: E(T) and { {1,5}, {5,3}, {3,1} }, since we are connecting leaves 1,5,3 into a cycle.

Comment: And what about vertex #4 ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, you are right, it was a typo, sorry. I just fixed this.

Comment: @xan Did you hear about the Grötzsch theorem for triangle-free planar graphs? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch's_theorem

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local Edges_of_Tree = {{1,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {4,5}}
local Cycle_of_Leaves = {1,5,3}

local color1 = 'Red'
local color2 = 'Green'
local color3 = 'Blue'

local vert = {}     
local vert_arr = {}  

local function add_edge(v1, v2)
   assert(v1 ~= v2)
   if not vert[v1] then
      vert[v1] = {deg = 0, adj = {}}
      table.insert(vert_arr, v1)
   end
   vert[v1].deg = vert[v1].deg + 1
   assert(not vert[v1].adj[v2], 'multiple edges between '..v1..' and '..v2)
   vert[v1].adj[v2] = true
end

for _, edge in ipairs(Edges_of_Tree) do
   local v1, v2 = unpack(edge)
   add_edge(v1, v2)
   add_edge(v2, v1)
end

table.sort(vert_arr)

local leaf_ctr = 0
local root
for v, vv in pairs(vert) do
   if vv.deg == 1 then
      leaf_ctr = leaf_ctr + 1
   else
      root = v
   end
end
assert(#vert_arr > leaf_ctr + 1, 'tree is a star')
assert(leaf_ctr == #Cycle_of_Leaves, 'invalid Cycle_of_Leaves')
for _, v in ipairs(Cycle_of_Leaves) do
   assert(vert[v] and vert[v].deg == 1 and vert[v].color == nil, 
      'invalid Cycle_of_Leaves')
   vert[v].color = false
end

local function recursive_paint_inodes(v, color, prev_v)
   assert(vert[v].color == nil, 'a cycle in tree found')
   vert[v].color = color
   local next_color = (color1..color2):gsub(color, '')
   for next_v in pairs(vert[v].adj) do
      if next_v ~= prev_v and vert[next_v].deg > 1 then
         recursive_paint_inodes(next_v, next_color, v)
      end
   end
end
recursive_paint_inodes(root, color1)

local front
for i = 1, leaf_ctr do
   local vv = vert[Cycle_of_Leaves[i]]
   vv.next = Cycle_of_Leaves[i % leaf_ctr + 1]
   vv.prev = Cycle_of_Leaves[(i - 2) % leaf_ctr + 1]
   local parent = next(vv.adj)
   if parent ~= next(vert[vv.prev].adj) then
      assert(not vert[parent].conn_to_leaf, 'graph is non-planar')
      vert[parent].conn_to_leaf = true
      front = Cycle_of_Leaves[i]
   end
end

vert[next(vert[vert[front].prev].adj)].color = color3
vert[front].color = color3

local tricolor = color1..color2..color3
local leaf = front
for i = 1, leaf_ctr - 1 do
   local prev_color = vert[leaf].color
   leaf = vert[leaf].next
   local parent_color = vert[next(vert[leaf].adj)].color
   local enabled_colors = tricolor:gsub(prev_color, ''):gsub(parent_color, '')
   vert[leaf].color = enabled_colors:match(color1)
      or enabled_colors:match(color2) or color3
end

for _, v in ipairs(vert_arr) do
   print(v..' '..vert[v].color)
end
```

This code is written in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/index.html).
You can test it in action [there](http://codepad.org/5mMfTrDv).

Comment: Want to upvote!  Can't, since it's an opaque wall of text.  Any explanation as to how it works?

Comment: @phs - It is not an algorithm completely explained.  It is just a source of hints how to build your own algorithm.  And, of course, this "wall of text" works.  Additionally, it could be considered as advertisement of wonderful and powerful language Lua.  I love it. :-)